# when running a test, junit complains "no tests found" - using intellij + want to use junit4

Tags: intellij-idea, junit

assertion error "no tests found"

- junit
- maven
- intellij

renaming the method from `blah` to `testBlah` fixes it, the test is found and runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. delete the test file
2. open the class you want to test
3. press `ctrl+shift+t` and create a new test
4. change the testing library to junit4 (was junit3)